# How do I set a query result equal to a variable in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table titled `MIUInfo`. In it there are three columns; `MIUID`, `Latitude`, and `Longitude`.
In it I'm running the following query which gets the number of `MIUID`s in the criteria range.

```
SELECT Count(MIUInfo.MIUID)
      From MIUInfo 
      WHERE ((MIUInfo.Latitude Between " & minLat & " And " & maxLat & ") 
      AND (MIUInfo.Longitude Between " & minLong & " And " & maxLong & "))
```

I need to set the result of this query equal to a variable in VBA so that I can use it as a condition for a loop. I can't figure out how to do this.

Also, when I try to use the `DoCmd.RunSQL` command I get an error:

> Run-time error '2342':  A RunSQL action requires an argument of an SQL statement.

The only difference between this query and others I'm running with the `DoCmd.RunSQL` is that all of the other select queries are generating a new table.

Comment: And my question is getting down-voted because..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access the easiest way to do this is with the [DCount](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dcount.php) function:

```
Total = DCount("MIUInfo.MIUID", "MIUInfo", "(MIUInfo.Latitude Between " & minLat & " And " & maxLat & ") AND (MIUInfo.Longitude Between " & minLong & " And " & maxLong & ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DCOUNT](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dcount.php)